# error deploying scala app on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, scala, scalatra

Iam trying to develop a scala web app and try to deploy in to GAE. While deploying app from the sbt appengine prompt (appengine-deploy), I get this error. I have no clue why its happening but deploying on a local works fine.

```
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=jugcep&version=1.0&
```

500 Internal Server Error

Server Error (500)
A server error has occurred.

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=jugcep&version=1.0&
500 Internal Server Error

Server Error (500)
A server error has occurred.

Please see the logs [/var/folders/2L/2LXF1rCtFnaVepqm8nLO8E+++TI/-Tmp-/appcfg2634201961391003721.log] for further information.
[error] 
[error] {file:/Users/prassee/scalaWorkspace/jcep/}default-479528/compile:appengine-deploy: error executing appcfg
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed Apr 18, 2012 10:11:48 PM

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:260)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
at sbt.BasicIO$.read$1(ProcessImpl.scala:108)
at sbt.BasicIO$.transferFullyImpl(ProcessImpl.scala:112)
at sbt.BasicIO$.transferFully(ProcessImpl.scala:88)
at sbt.BasicIO$.connectToIn(ProcessImpl.scala:79)
at sbt.BasicIO$$anonfun$input$1.apply(ProcessImpl.scala:80)
at sbt.BasicIO$$anonfun$input$1.apply(ProcessImpl.scala:80)
at sbt.SimpleProcessBuilder$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(ProcessImpl.scala:383)
at sbt.Spawn$$anon$3.run(ProcessImpl.scala:20)
```

Comment: We can't possibly help unless you show us the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Scala is not officially supported on GAE, but of course it works as long as it can not differentiate as long as it looks like Java class/JARs.

From the stack trace, what I can think is that whatever you are trying to do is trying to access filesystem for writing, which wont be possible because GAE does not write writes to its filesystem. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

How large is the application you're deploying? There are som limits on size, however they should be sufficient for most: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine#Hard_limits

Do you know how far the deploy gets before the pipe breaks? Is it at the very beginning?